# excel vba for loop changing steps

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that averages daily values into monthly values. The difficulty I found was that each month have different days of the month so I figured I had to change the steps in my loop. My program runs fine but the logic to the correct steps are a bit off.

```
lastrow2 = Range(Sheets("Daily").Cells(5, 3), Sheets("Daily").Cells(5, 3).End(xlDown)).Count
lastcol2 = Range(Sheets("Daily").Cells(5, 3), Sheets("Daily").Cells(5, 3).End(xlToRight)).Count

irow2 = 5
cnt = 5
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For j2 = 3 To lastcol1 + 3                              'number of columns in the dataset
nextmo:
        If Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 1 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 60 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 121 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 182 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 213 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 274 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 335 Then
            daysofthemo = 31
        ElseIf Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 91 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 152 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 244 Or Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 305 Then
            daysofthemo = 30
        ElseIf Sheets("Daily").Cells(i2, 2) = 32 Then
            daysofthemo = 28
        End If

        For i2 = cnt To lastrow1 + 5 Step daysofthemo         'number of rows in the dataset

            'Will now take the average of one month and paste onto worksheet called "monthly"
            Set myRange2 = Range(wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(i2, j2), wb.Worksheets("Daily").Cells(i2 + daysofthemo - 1, j2))
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(myRange2) > 0 Then
                wb.Worksheets("Monthly").Cells(irow2, j2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myRange2)
            End If
            irow2 = irow2 + 1
            cnt = i2 + daysofthemo
            goto nextmo
        Next i2
    Next j2
```

I have msgbox before and after the if statement. 
The output should be:
274, 31, 305, 30, 335, 31, 1, 31, and so on.

But right now the output is: 274, 31, 305, 30, 336, 30, 2, 33, and so on.

Just thought of this new code, tested but still not right.

Comment: The `To` and the `Step` parts of a `For` loop are only evaluated once at the start of the loop, you can't change them once in the loop.

Comment: How are you calculating daysofthemonth? EOmonth would help

Comment: Your `Step` doesn't change how many loops are performed, it changes the increments that it loops by.

Comment: Is there any other method to work around this?
@Nathan_Sav daysofthemonth are constants 31,30, or 28 depending on the month

Comment: look at the `AVERAGEIFS` function. It may be able to even eliminate your VBA. Or even an 'AVERAGE(IF(` array.

Comment: So if you are to use them, you'll need to pick one, so you could either calculate the step before instigating the loop, or you could use an array, of the months, then retrieve via, arrMonthDays(intMonthNum) where you populate the months yourself.

Comment: You need to calculate the max day of the month before the inner loop starts.  If you cannot do that; always loop 31 times and use `EXIT FOR` to break out early (when required).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with arrays, but @destination-data gave me an idea. I edited my code haven't tried it yet

Comment: What is the value of `lastcol1` ? I do not see where u declare or set it...

Comment: You reference `cells` to a sheet, but not `range` in the same line...
Also, sometimes you use `wb.` and then most of the time not....

Answer (score 0):

```
intDaysInMonth=DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(dtDate), Month(dtDate), 1), WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dtDate, 0)) + 1
```